blacklist token
I would like to know how I can create a black list on Solana, with solidity I do:
function updateBlacklist(address _address, bool _isBlacklisted) public {
    isBlacklisted[_address] = _isBlacklisted;
    emit Blacklist(_address, _isBlacklisted);
}

